# download pdf file from database but its downloading some unknown format

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, pdf

I have uploaded a PDF file into a MS SQL Server database and while I fetch it back from database as bytes and try to download it, it downloads some file but its not PDF file.

My code:

```
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["PDFDbColumnName"];
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    valid.Text = "File Downloaded";
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: How do you know the bytes aren't PDF bytes? What are the first bytes?

Comment: bytes are the PDF bytes which are being fetched from database but when it downloads, its not the PDF file. Its some unknown format.

Comment: You aren't answering my question. Show me the first bytes that you receive from the database. How do you know that it's an unknown format? What do you expect from people who want to answer this question? Your question sounds like: *"I have a file of an unknown format; please tell me which format this is?"* **Nobody** can answer that question *unless you show the first bytes of that "unknown" file.*

Comment: No, that's not my question at all. My question is: I want to download PDF file which is being fetched from database as varbinary.

Comment: These are the bytes: 0x255044462D312E350D0A25B5B5B5B50D0A312030206F626A0D0A3C3C2F547970652F436174616C6F672F50616765732032203020522F4C616E6728656E2D555329202F53747275637454726565526F6F74203335203020522F4D61726B496E666F3C3C2F4D61726B656420747275653E3E3E3E0D0A656E646F626A0D0A322030

Comment: You claim that the bytes are in an unknown format, but that's not true. The bytes are PDF bytes, but you present them in hexadecimal form:    25 = %
    50 = P
    44 = D
    46 = F
    2D = -
    31 = 1
    2E = .
    35 = 5
    
That's exactly how a PDF file starts. You need to extract the bytes as bytes, not as a hexidecimal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question but are you sure it's not just you haven't given it an extension in the filename (and so its an unknown format?)?

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName");
```

Try

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf");
```

Comment: This doesn't matter. The bytes he receives are PDF. He just doesn't see it.

Comment: It's not he doesn't see it, he doesn't indicate if he has tried to open it (and in what application). It may be he is seeing a file download but it has no extension so his browser does not know which application to open it with.

Comment: No, the browser can't do anything with a hexadecimal string. He needs to write his bytes as bytes, not as a hexadecimal string.

Comment: yeah, it was a silly question but it does happen with you when you are so confused. I was just missing the .pdf with the file name. Thanks for it :)